# Convert a Collection of Strings into Collection of GUID

Tags: c#, excel, linq, guid

I am reading a `collection of strings (of GUID format)` from `excel` and want to store them in database as `collection of GUIDs`.  I am just wondering is there any clean way to convert `List<string>` to `List<Guid>` using `Linq`. I am not interested in looping through.

Comment: Either the way Neil has shown(which also loops under the hood) or `var list = guidStrings.ConvertAll(Guid.Parse);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either LINQ:

```
List<Guid> guids = guidStrings.Select(Guid.Parse).ToList();
```

or `List.ConvertAll` which is a little bit more efficient because it knows the size:

```
List<Guid> guids = guidStrings.ConvertAll(Guid.Parse);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yep

```
IEnumerable<Guid> guids = guidStrings.Select(x => Guid.Parse(x));
```

Or as juharr said in their comment below, you can simplify this a little to a "method group":

```
IEnumerable<Guid> guids = guidStrings.Select(Guid.Parse);
```

Because C# can work out that the only argument passed-in is the same as the only argument required by `Guid.Parse()` so the compiler does it for you.

Comment: Or just `Select(Guid.Parse)`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to take advantage of the [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) method which can map each of your individual strings to a corresponding `Guid` :

```
// This will parse each string present in your strings collection to its cooresponding guid
var guids = strings.Select(Guid.Parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done:

```
IEnumerable<string> guidStrings = ..... // GUID-compatible strigns
List<Guid> guids = guidStrings.Select(s => new Guid(s)).ToList();
```